# How to add facebook open source code pop to project directly

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-pop

I have downloaded the facebook open source code **pop** from [github](https://github.com/facebook/pop/blob/master/pop/POP.h). But all header files are imported like this: `#import <POP/POPAnimatableProperty.h>`. What should I to  do with project setting to support import file like this in my project. I know that I can run it by replace all `#import <POP/XXX.h>` with `#import XXX.h` but I'd to use the open source like the pop sample project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through learning cocoapod project, I have got how to config project. Config pop file path to system path, then I can include pod with `#import <POP/POP.h>`.

1. Add a new `configuration setting file`, edit file with following content:

   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${SRCROOT}/Library" "${SRCROOT}/Library/pop"
   OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) "-isystem${SRCROOT}/Library" "-isystem${SRCROOT}/Library/pop"
2. Put pop folder to `${SRCROOT}/Library` dictionary. 
   [image: Where to put Pop Source]
3. In project setting, info tab,  set configurations with the new configuration file.

[image: How to set configuration file]

Comment: can u tell me how to set configuration with the new configuration file?

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput I have edited my answer with a Image

Comment: i am unable to understand your second step. Please tell me with example

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput I have edit my answer. The path is depended on the configuration file content actually, and I think you should understand it first.

Comment: hi, i have the problem "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: _OBJC_CLASS_$_POPSpringAnimation" followed these steps in xcode6, any idea?